# Page Fault - How does os search for the page in secondary storage?

Tags: operating-system, paging, page-tables

My question is when a page fault occurs and the required page is not in RAM ,after that how does the os know where to look for the given page in the entire secondary memory to bring it to the RAM? So is the logical address the address of the secondary memory store or is the required secondary storage address stored in the page table itself or some other way?
I feel like i am probably missing something very basic here but this doubt came in my mind and a quick google search is not providing any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is when a page fault occurs and the required page is not in RAM ,after that how does the os know where to look for the given page in the entire secondary memory to bring it to the RAM?

If there were 50 different operating systems that supported an average of 10 different architectures each, there would be up to a maximum of 500 different answers; where one of the answers would be "*all software uses physical addresses and there is no virtual memory and there is no secondary memory*" and another answer would be "*a virtual address is a location on the disk and RAM is just used as disk cache to speed it up*" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_store ).

For most typical modern operating systems running on most typical architectures; if you worked out all of the information the kernel needs to know about each virtual page (e.g. what the page is pretending to be, what the page actually is, location on disk if any, location in RAM if any, something to keep track of "least recently used", something to keep track of "number of copy-on-write copies", etc); then you could scatter all the information across multiple different data structures such that:

- some of the data structures are used/required by the CPU itself and some aren't
- the same information may or may not be in 2 or more data structures at the same time
- some data structures have an entry for each virtual page and some just have an entry for each range of multiple pages
- some data structures are arrays/tables, some are trees, some are trees of tables, and some are something else.
- some use "virtual address" or "virtual page number" as a key to find information; and some use something else (e.g. inverted page tables on PowerPC and Itanium use "physical address" as an index because using what you're trying to find as an index is the least intelligent thing you could possibly do, so why not?).
- some of the data structures may be in the kernel and some may not be (e.g. the L4 micro-kernel manages virtual memory mapping purely in user-space via. an "abstract hierarchical address space" model).

In general; the information about where a page's data is in (each different piece of?) secondary memory (if there is secondary memory) will be stored in one or more places in one or more things.

Note that when a page fault occurs the page fault handler typically needs to make multiple decisions; possibly starting with figuring out what made the access (a process, the kernel itself?) and whether the access should be allowed or denied, then figuring out what to do about it (send `SIGSEGV`? do a kernel panic? fetch data into the CPU's TLB? invalidate stale data from CPU's TLB? do copy-on-write cloning? fetch data from swap space? fetch data from file?); so the page fault handler ends up finding multiple different pieces of data from (potentially) multiple different places.

**A Concrete Example**

For my OS designs (which are based on asynchronous message passing and use micro-kernels); a micro-kernel is small enough that it can be custom designed and optimised for a specific architecture (without any regard to portability). The operating system design is intended for distributed systems, and for that reason shared memory (and `fork()`) are not supported (you don't want page fault handler to have to fetch data from a remote computer over a congested network connection to do a "copy on write"); and the only case for "copy on write" is memory mapped files where the page is shared by one or more processes and the (local) VFS cache.

For 64-bit 80x86, the CPU requires a tree of 4 levels of tables (page tables, page directories, page directory pointer tables and page map level 4), and to improve efficiency (reduce memory consumption and reduce cache misses, etc) I use these tables as much as possible.

For page table entries (or page directory entries if 2 MiB pages are being used); if the page is not present there are 63 bits that are ignored by the CPU that the OS can use for its own purposes; and if the page is present then (depending on which features CPU supports) there are at least 9 bits that the OS can use for its own purposes and flags that the CPU uses (e.g. the "read, write, no-execute" flags) can be used to augment the OS's own information.

When a page is not present, the 63-bits are split into 2 fields - one 8 bit field to keep track of the virtual type of the page (if it's supposed to act like RAM, if it's supposed to be executable, if it's supposed to use "write-back" caching, etc), and one 55 bit "where" field. If the highest bit in the "where" field is set the page was sent to swap space and the other 54 bits are a "swap space handle" (allowing for a maximum of "2**54 * 4 KiB" of swap space); and if the highest bit in the "where" field is clear then the other 54 bits are a "memory mapped file handle". If a page fault occurs because of a "not present" page, the page fault handler uses the 8-bit field to determine if the access should be allowed or denied (or if it's already being handled due to a different thread accessing it already), then (if the access should be allowed) the page fault handler tells the scheduler to put the thread in a "WAITING FOR PAGE" state and marks the page as "being fetched" (so that other threads that belong to the same process know that it's being fetched already), then uses the "where" field to either send a request message asking for the page's data to the Swap Manager (which is a process in user-space), or to find a "memory mapped file descriptor" structure in kernel space that contains more information (that didn't fit in the page table entry) to determine the offset of the page within the file and a file handle, and send a request to the VFS for the page's data (the VFS or Virtual File System is another process in user-space). Later; when Swap Manager or VFS send a reply message containing the page's data back to the kernel, the kernel fixes up the page table entry (putting the page of data from the message into the virtual address space) and tells scheduler to unblock the thread/s (shift them from the "WAITING FOR PAGE" state to the "READY TO RUN" state).

For both of these cases (memory mapped file and swap space) if the access was an "allowed read" then the page is mapped as read only (regardless of whether the page is supposed to be writeable). If the access was an "allowed write", or if a later "allowed write" is done to a page that was previously fetched and mapped as read only; then if the page's data came from swap space the page fault handler informs the Swap Manager that the copy of the page in swap space can be discarded (can't be re-used if the same page is sent to swap space later), and if the page's data came from a memory mapped file the page fault handler informs the VFS that there's one less process with a copy of that page and copies the "copy on write" page's data to a newly allocated page.

When a page is "present", it may still be part of a memory mapped file and there may still be a copy in swap space; but there isn't enough space in the page table entry to store the "where" field. In this case, if the page is in swap space and in RAM, the Swap Manager has to accept "Process ID + virtual address" instead of a "swap space handle" (which causes a little extra overhead in Swap Manager because it has to convert "Process ID + virtual address" into "swap space handle" itself). If the page is a "copy on write" memory mapped file, then the page fault handler searches the process' list of "memory mapped file descriptors" (which causes a little extra overhead).

Note that (in theory) when an OS is running low on free RAM it wants to select a "least likely to be needed soon" page to send to swap space, but this isn't easy/practical so most operating systems use "least recently used" instead.
My kernels don't do this at all. Instead they just send "random" pages to the Swap Manager, and (initially) the Swap Manager keeps the data in RAM and doesn't send it to any of the swap providers to store; and the Swap Manager uses "least recently sent to swap manager" to figure out which pages to send to a swap provider to store. A page that is used often may be sent to swap manager many times without ever actually being sent to a swap provider (and without causing slow disk IO for frequently used pages). Also note that, because "copy on write memory mapped file" is the only case that "copy on write" is used and because there is no other form of shared memory, the VFS can keep track of how many processes are sharing a copy of pages itself and the kernel never need to keep track of how many processes are sharing a copy of any page (like most kernels for most operating systems do).

Comment: So I guess the answer is that there are so many different ways that fetching of page data can occur that it is hard to give a definite answer? In that case, can you give a very barebones basic example that you know of how the page is fetched from the secondary storage starting from the page fault occurring?

Comment: @UdayanBaidya: I've added a concrete example for one OS (that probably won't help you understand how it works for any other OS).

Comment: I guess this part - " send a request message asking for the page's data to the Swap Manager (which is a process in user-space), or to find a "memory mapped file descriptor" structure in kernel space that contains more information (that didn't fit in the page table entry) to determine the offset of the page within the file and a file handle " is the answer I was looking for. I am still not fully clear on the actions swap manager take to search for the missing page but I guess trying to go deeper would only confuse me further from here on :P. Thanks for your explanation. :)